# The first row when single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: oracle, subquery

My subquery returns more than one row and I need the first row and keep my max function

```
Select ...
Where GHTY_FIRME.FIRME_ID= (Select   FIRME_ID
                           FROM imag_verification_tube 
                           WHERE (numero_dossier =  '12004' OR NUMERO_TIRE= '12004')
                           AND CREE_LE = (select max (CREE_LE) 
                           from tableX where(numero_dossier ='12004' OR 
                           NUMERO_PQDCS= '12004 ')));
```

Comment: What does your "from clause" look like in the first clause?

Comment: You could probably use analytic functions, but you need to provide more data to get the right answers

Comment: Use the `IN` condition, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`rownum`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) pseudocolumn:

```
Select ...
Where GHTY_FIRME.FIRME_ID= (Select   FIRME_ID
                           FROM imag_verification_tube 
                           WHERE (numero_dossier =  '12004' OR NUMERO_TIRE= '12004')
                           AND CREE_LE = (select max (CREE_LE) 
                                          from tableX 
                                          where(numero_dossier ='12004' 
                                               OR NUMERO_PQDCS= '12004 ') 
                                               and rownum < 2));
```

See also [On ROWNUM and Limiting Results](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html).

That said, you can try to optimize the sql. One of the first things I would do is to convert the inner SQLs to joins. Also, depending on your business logic, the or condition *could* also be elminated.